# Finding location of jacoco agent jar in gradle (3.3)

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to do test coverage analysis on a application server and do not want to manually manage the jacoco version between unit tests and end to end tests. 
Is there way to get the path for the agent from within a gradle task to I can rely on gradle to keep jacoco agent versions between the plugin and manual attachment consistent.

The ultimate goal is to run the server with jacoco agent attached and collect test coverage info during end to end tests.

Comment: can you attach your current build.gradle?

Comment: The only relevant part is that I am using the jacoco plugin.
`apply plugin: "jacoco"` and the plugin does not indicate where it keeps the jar files.

Comment: I have added some thoughts in my answer, let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the agent as a dependency. According to page http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/repo.html : Maven coordinates - `groupdId` is `org.jacoco`, `artifactId` is `org.jacoco.agent` and `classifier` is `runtime`. This is the same artifact that is packaged into JAR that provides access to the agent as resource (`org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent` aka "API to get a local copy of the agent") and that is used by Gradle JaCoCo Plugin. Version can be specified as variable for consistency between Gradle JaCoCo Plugin and dependency.

Comment: It's not ideal, but it is better than guessing or maintaining 2 version numbers in the config. I now have a single version for the plugin and the agent. Let's hope agent and plugin will remain in version sync.

Answer (score 2):

Accordingly to [Gradle doc](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html), jacoco closure would config `toolVersion` to control the `jacocoagent` version.

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
}
```

Here is the [gradle source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/jacoco/src/main/java/org/gradle/internal/jacoco/JacocoAgentJar.java#L59-L74) to resolve the `jacocoagent.jar`:

```
/**
 * Unzips the resolved {@code org.jacoco.agent.jar} to retrieve the {@code jacocoagent.jar}.
 *
 * @return a file pointing to the {@code jacocoagent.jar}
 */
public File getJar() {
    if (agentJar == null) {
        agentJar = project.zipTree(getAgentConf().getSingleFile()).filter(new Spec<File>() {
            @Override
            public boolean isSatisfiedBy(File file) {
                return file.getName().equals("jacocoagent.jar");
            }
        }).getSingleFile();
    }
    return agentJar;
}
```

In fact, if you downloaded the jar (e.g. `org.jacoco.agent-0.7.6.201602180812.jar`) and unzip it, you will see it is on top level:

```
$ unzip org.jacoco.agent-0.7.6.201602180812.jar
Archive:  org.jacoco.agent-0.7.6.201602180812.jar
  inflating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF    
  inflating: META-INF/MTNMINDS.SF    
  inflating: META-INF/MTNMINDS.RSA   
   creating: META-INF/maven/
   creating: META-INF/maven/org.jacoco/
   creating: META-INF/maven/org.jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/
  inflating: META-INF/maven/org.jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/pom.xml  
  inflating: META-INF/maven/org.jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/pom.properties  
   creating: org/
   creating: org/jacoco/
   creating: org/jacoco/agent/
  inflating: jacocoagent.jar         
  inflating: org/jacoco/agent/AgentJar.class  
  inflating: about.html
```

Let me know if this helps.